# how to detect nullable when call java in kotlin

Tags: java, kotlin, nullable

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1){
            val callingPkg = referrer.host
```

when I use these code in Kotlin to get the referrer of an Activity, I came across a crash:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: referrer must not be null

The reason is referrer is null, but I read the code the getReferrer is already marked `@Nullable`
Why can IDE notify me that this may cause Null?
Compared to that I write my class as：

```
public class LilyTest {
    @Nullable
    public Uri getUri(){
        long millis = System.currentTimeMillis();
        return  millis %2 == 1 ? null:new Uri.Builder().scheme("android-app").authority("mReferrer").build();
    }
}
```

when I use

```
val pkg = LilyTest().uri.host
```

I can get error mark the line red, and explained "Only safe (?.) or non-null asserted (!!.) calls are allowed on a nullable receiver of type Uri?"

My question is why can't I get error notification when I use `referrer.host`, are there any diffs?

Answer (score 0):

> get the referrer of an Activity ... I read the code the getReferrer is already marked @Nullable

According to the documentation [it isn't](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#getReferrer()), though the comment says it can indeed return null. You can use [external annotations](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/external-annotations.html) to mark it (Kotlin understands them since 1.3.40, see "Using External annotations in IntelliJ IDEA" [here](https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2019/06/kotlin-1-3-40-released/)).

Comment: thanks for your reply, reaIly good idea, I tried but failed, even I replace the test method with external annotation, in Kotlin it can not show the error, for the "referrer" it does not work either
Don't know whether not work in Android studio or any other reason

Comment: You could try to ask on https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/ as well.

Comment: Wouldn't `val callingPkg = referrer.host` throw NullPointerException and not IllegalArgumentException if `referrer` were null? Are we even chasing the right issue?